# Compilation error App_Web_tdichmin.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

i'm facing this kind of error for the first time, please tell me what is this error actually and how to resolve it.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

> CS0006: Metadata file
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\014679fc\1b393534\App_Web_tdichmin.dll' could not be found

please help me with this....

thank you.

Comment: App_Web_tdichmin.dll is missing. Check your bin folder

Comment: yes App_web_tdichmin.dll file not there in my project. so where can i get this file..

Comment: Was it there before?

Comment: no sir... it's not there before.

Comment: Is 'App_Web_tdichmin' your project name?

Comment: no sir.. my project name is administrator. before that it's working fine. i added one webpage and coded it. when i try to run that page i'm getting this error..

Comment: I think you need to rebuild your solution

Comment: Close your project. Open it again. Right click on your solution,in solution explorer and click on rebuild. Then try to run.

Comment: thank you... now pages are opening in the browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your project, open it again, Click on Clean as shown in the image, then rebuild.
[image]

Comment: yes getting same error.. but different file name.  App_Web_ehyemsi1.dll could not be found

Comment: Well, that is strange. Try repeating the steps again.